# 2003 Chevy Silverado

Tags: engine, chevrolet, silverado, compression

Why does my 2003 Chevy Silverado 2 door pickup LQ4 Vin U engine Why does my 2003 Chevy Silverado LQ4 engine have no compression in one cylinder

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! How do you know this one cylinder doesn't have compression? What symptoms is it giving you?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons, all of which are reasonably large problems:

1. The spark plug is missing.
2. One or more of the valves is broken or stuck.
3. The piston is messed up or the piston rings are damaged.
4. The cylinder head is broken or the head gasket is damaged.
5. The engine block is broken.

I'd start by checking what I could from the outside.  If you have a borescope remove the spark plug and have a look inside.

Pull the cylinder head and see what's going on inside.